# Blocking email address that is surrounded by quotes

Tags: outlook.com, spam-prevention

**How do I block repetitive scam emails to my hotmail.com email account from a source address with invalid characters in it?**

I am receiving constant emails many times per day that look like this:

[image: Email image]

This email is obviously a bogus, unwanted piece of junk.  I made the mistake of attempting to unsubscribe by replying as instructed.  This only increased the frequency in which I receive them, assumedly by making it clear to them that my account is active.

I have attempted to use Hotmail/Outlook features to block this address; however, normal means do not work.  The address will not be added to my Blocked List automatically, nor can I add it manually.  This appears to be because the email address contains quotes surrounding it, which is not considered to be a valid address.

[image: Address Closeup]

[image: Blocking Screenshot]

**How is this email address even possible?  How can I successfully block this address and these emails?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The issue has solved itself.**

After several days of receiving this junk mail in my inbox, mail from this sender has now started appearing in my junk folder.  It is possible that this issue was fixed in the web app itself.